# electron-packager with angular 2 Error: spawn ENOTDIR:

Tags: angular, electron

I am executing thee following script;

```
electron-packager bin/desktopBuild --version 1.4.3 --platform linux --out ./MyApp
```

but am getting following error;

```
electron-packager bin/desktopBuild --version 1.4.3 --platform linux --out ./MyApp

Packaging app for platform linux x64 using electron v1.4.3
internal/child_process.js:313
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn ENOTDIR
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1036:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:313:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:380:9)
    at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:143:15)
    at Object.exports.exec (child_process.js:103:18)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/var/www/project/node_modules/electron-packager/common.js:248:15)
    at each (/var/www/project/node_modules/run-series/index.js:17:24)
    at CB (/var/www/project/node_modules/electron-packager/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/remove/rimraf.js:60:5)
    at /var/www/project/node_modules/electron-packager/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/remove/rimraf.js:110:14
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-57-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "desktop-build-packager"
npm ERR! node v6.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! project@0.1.0 desktop-build-packager: `electron-packager bin/desktopBuild --version 1.4.3 --platform linux --out ./MyApp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the s2a@0.1.0 desktop-build-packager script 'electron-packager bin/desktopBuild --version 1.4.3 --platform linux --out ./MyApp'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the project package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     electron-packager bin/desktopBuild --version 1.4.3 --platform linux --out ./MyApp
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs project
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls project
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/s2a/npm-debug.log
```

**npm-debug.log**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'desktop-build-packager' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.3
3 info using node@v6.7.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predesktop-build-packager',
4 verbose run-script   'desktop-build-packager',
4 verbose run-script   'postdesktop-build-packager' ]
5 info lifecycle project@0.1.0~predesktop-build-packager: project@0.1.0
6 silly lifecycle project@0.1.0~predesktop-build-packager: no script for predesktop-build-packager, continuing
7 info lifecycle project@0.1.0~desktop-build-packager: s2aproject0.1.0
8 verbose lifecycle project@0.1.0~desktop-build-packager: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle project@0.1.0~desktop-build-packager: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/project/node_modules/.bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
10 verbose lifecycle project@0.1.0~desktop-build-packager: CWD: /var/www/project
11 silly lifecycle project@0.1.0~desktop-build-packager: Args: [ '-c',
11 silly lifecycle   'electron-packager bin/desktopBuild --version 1.4.3 --platform linux --out ./MyApp' ]
12 silly lifecycle project@0.1.0~desktop-build-packager: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle project@0.1.0~desktop-build-packager: Failed to exec desktop-build-packager script
14 verbose stack Error: project@0.1.0 desktop-build-packager: `electron-packager bin/desktopBuild --version 1.4.3 --platform linux --out ./MyApp`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:242:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid project@0.1.0
16 verbose cwd /var/www/project
17 error Linux 4.4.0-57-generic
18 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "desktop-build-packager"
19 error node v6.7.0
20 error npm  v3.10.3
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error project@0.1.0 desktop-build-packager: `electron-packager bin/desktopBuild --version 1.4.3 --platform linux --out ./MyApp`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the project@0.1.0 desktop-build-packager script 'electron-packager bin/desktopBuild --version 1.4.3 --platform linux --out ./MyApp'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the project package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     electron-packager bin/desktopBuild --version 1.4.3 --platform linux --out ./MyApp
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs project
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls project
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

If need more detail please let me know ..

Comment: So, have you investigated that NPM Debug log?

Comment: @Makoto please review my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out by myself its saying in this command `electron-packager bin/desktopBuild --version 1.4.3 --platform linux --out ./MyApp`  ..... `bin/desktopBuild` is not a valid directory ...